# Set different session data - two different sessions

Tags: php, session

```
<?php
session_start();

$session_new_name_1 = session_name("user1");
$session_new_name_2 = session_name("user2");

$_SESSION['user_name'] = "John";  //set to $session_new_name_1
$_SESSION['user_name'] = "Frank"; //set to $session_new_name_2

?>
```

The question is basically, how can i set the name John to the session user1 and the name Frank to the session user2?

The two sessions should coexist.

Comment: not getting clearly, can you please elaborate you question

Comment: @LearneR, I need two sessions at the same time, each one with different data.

Comment: What is the point of having two different sessions within one script? You can just keep the variables using different names.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski, for example destroy only the data of the user 2. Session_destroy(user2); will be much more clean and easier. Well, i don't know if this is possible.

Comment: As you can see in the answers it is not. You can store objects or different arrays within one session if your concern is clarity. You can then `unset($_SESSION['user1'])` to unset the array which keeps all the data for `user1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want some more data you can do it this way:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = array('name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Doe', 'email' => 'some@mail.com');
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. The PHPSESSID can only contain one ID. Moreover session_name() needs to be called before session_start(). From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php).

> The session name is reset to the default value stored in session.name at request startup time. Thus, you need to call session_name() for every request (and before session_start() or session_register() are called).

However, if you're not really looking for a true double session system the answer provided by @ripa and @phpalix may help you.

Comment: It's easy to generate different cookies (the OP actually does it right) but I couldn't find a way to give them different *values*, so they end up pointing to the same data. You'd also need to switch sessions every time (no way to read both at the same time). To sum up: it's a painful way to abuse sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Make the session an array, in your example:

```
$_SESSION['user_name']['user1'] = "John";
$_SESSION['user_name']['user1'] = "Frank";
```

[Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) are powerful and can help you overcome many problems if used correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['user1'] = "John"; 
$_SESSION['user2'] = "Frank";
```

try this. may help you.